# want to store multiple file path in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, upload

Hi i want to store multiple file path in database, but the following code is storing just one file path

Kindly some one help.

**My Controller**

```
<?php    
class upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view("header.php");
        $this->load->view('main_views', array('error' => ' ' ));
        $this->load->view("footer.php");
    }

function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2000';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        // no file uploaded or failed upload
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view("header.php");
        $this->load->view('main_views', $error);
        $this->load->view("footer.php");
    }
    else
    {
       $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->model('post_model');
        $this->post_model->main_model();

        $this->load->view("header.php");

        $this->load->view('main_views');
        $this->load->view("footer.php");

    }
}
?>
```

**My Model**

```
<?php
class post_model extends CI_Model
{

    function main_model()
    { 
        $filepath = $this->upload->data()['file_name']; 
        $this->db->trans_begin();

        $this->db->query("insert into post (post_pic)
         values ('$filepath')");


        $ad_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    }

}
?>
```

**Views**

```
                <span id="filediv"><input name="userfile" type="file" id="file"/>
       </span>
                <span id="filediv"><input name="userfile2" type="file" id="file"/>
       </span>
                <span id="filediv"><input name="userfile3" type="file" id="file"/>
       </span>
                <span id="filediv"><input name="userfile2" type="file" id="file"/></span><br/>
```

extra text due to parsing rule kindly ignore it extra text due to parsing rule kindly ignore it extra text due to parsing rule kindly ignore it extra text due to parsing rule kindly ignore it extra text due to parsing rule kindly ignore it

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). and your HTML is incorrect. You have the same ID for your spans and file inputs, which is not permitted. DOM IDs **MUST** be unique across the entire document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple upload of codeignter

https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Views
- input name change to **name="userfile[]"**

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload each $_FILES

```
foreach ( $_FILES as $key => $value ) {

    if (! empty ( $value ['name'] )) {

        //change the file name
        $config ['file_name']       = date('Y_m_d') . '_' . $value ['name'];    
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (! $this->upload->do_upload ( $key )) {

            // handle error function
            $this->handle_error ( $this->upload->display_errors () );

        } else {

            $files [$i] = $this->upload->data ();
            ++ $i;
        }
    }
}
```

Here in $files array you will get the details of the uploaded files which can be used further for model to insert into database the path of the files.